# When to create a custom exception in C#

Tags: c#, exceptions, exception-handling

I'm writing a class to interface with a simple hardware device over a COM port.  The device can configured to use various modes, so my class has a `SetOperatingMode` function, that takes in an `enum` of type `UsbDeviceMode`.  It looks something like this:

```
class UsbDevice
{
    public void SetOperatingMode(UsbDeviceMode mode)
    { 
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
     buffer[0] = 0x5A;
     buffer[1] = 0x02;
     buffer[2] = (byte)mode;
     buffer[3] = 0x00; //IO_TYPE is always 0 in this case.

     _port.Write(buffer, 0, 4);
     int read = _port.Read(buffer, 0, 2);
     bool successfulSet = (read == 2 && buffer[0] == 0xFF && buffer[1] == 0x00);
    }
}

enum UsbDeviceMode
{
  IO_MODE = 0x00,
  IO_CHANGE = 0x10,
  I2C_S_20KHZ = 0x20,
  I2C_S_50KHZ = 0x30,
  I2C_S_100KHZ = 0x40,
  I2C_S_400KHZ = 0x50,
  I2C_H_100KHZ = 0x60,
  I2C_H_400KHZ = 0x70,
  I2C_H_1000KHZ = 0x80,
  SPI_MODE = 0x90,
  SERIAL = 0x01
};
```

There is the distinct possibility that this operation might fail due to any number of reasons:  The COM port might no longer exist, the device might have locked up or failed, or for whatever reason, the operation failed.

A failure would be unexpected, but not uncommon.  There's two distinct modes of failures:  The COM port throws an exception (`TimeoutException` and `InvalidOperationException` being the expected ones).  Or I could read back a failure indicator the device.

In any case, if `SetOperatingMode()` fails, then the device or the communication is broken somehow, and this class can't do anything about it.

I have 2 questions:

1. Should I "pre-throw" the `InvalidOperationException` if the port is closed?  From the MSDN documentation, `SerialPort.Write` and `SerialPort` read will throw if the port is closed.  I can check that at the very top of the function, or I can just let `_port.Write()` throw it.
2. Should there be an entirely new exception type thrown when `successfulSet` is `false`? If `successfulSet` is `false`, there's nothing that this class can do to.  Should there be some sort of `SetOperatingModeFailedException` exception to distinguish between the COM port failing or the device failing? It seems rather time consuming to create an entire exception class just for this one spot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a custom exception *when you want users to be able to programmatically distinguish between certain error conditions.*  If that situation does not exist, you can throw a more "general" exception, and avoid creating the custom exception class.

In the specific case of your `SetOperatingMode()` example, unless you need to call out specific ways that this method call might fail, you're better off using a more general exception.  In other words, if it's your intention to throw a `SetOperatingModeFailedException` exception as a possible result of calling `SetOperatingMode()`, but not to programmatically distinguish what kind of operating mode failure occurred, then you can dispense with creating a custom exception (since it's the only one that might be thrown), and simply throw an `InvalidOperationException`, which is probably the closest existing exception.

If you still want to create a custom exception, create one that is reusable across different methods, like `OperationFailedException`.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a class is easy.  It's not a time consuming process at all.  Debugging code which hides the problems is hard.  And time consuming.

When deciding to create an exception or not the question you should be asking yourself is "is this behaviour normal, expected behaviour, or is this behaviour exceptional".

In this case, the expected behaviour is that the operating mode is always set.  Therefore, I would suggest that exceptions need to be thrown.  I would allow any exceptions from the write operation bubble up.  I would also create a SetOperatingModeFailedException if the last line reveals an error has occurred.

In this case your method really only has the responsibility for trying to set the operating mode.  It doesn't have the responsibility to manage the connection.  That's someone else's responsibility and if it hasn't been done properly, an exception should be thrown.

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood what he's asking.  Should he use one of the existing exception types, or roll his own?

Comment: Actually I did answer his questions.  "I would allow any exceptions from the write operation bubble up." (i.e. don't bother checking if the port is opened) and "create a SetOperatingModeFailedException".

Comment: Pfft.  A custom exception is not necessary.  What other exception might the method throw, except whichever one that you chose?  How does SetOperatingModeFailedException add any value beyond, say, InvalidOperationException?  Neither exception tells you why the failure occurred, or gives you a way *to respond programmatically based on the type of exception that was thrown.*  And creating new Exception classes [is not cost-free](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: What value does it add?  It adds plenty of value when documented properly.  It says that this specific problem happened.  It's not clear that the calling code cannot recover from this error.

Comment: You can provide a detailed error message in whatever exception you throw.  Unless you plan on using specific exceptions to provide programmatic control to the caller, I think creating a custom exception is a waste of time.  Don't take my word for it, read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx), which says "Create your own user-defined exceptions if you want users to be able to programmatically distinguish between some error conditions."